# Ansible error when unpacking some archives into /usr/local/lib

Tags: ansible

I'm running an ansible playbook on my machine, and every task completes successfully except for several steps that involve unpacking various zip and tar.gz archives into `/usr/local/lib`. Here's an example of such an error message:

```
TASK: [sd_dev | Unpack /usr/local/lib/eclipse-standard-kepler-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz] ***
failed: [localhost] => {"failed": true}
msg: dest '/usr/local/lib' must be an existing dir
...ignoring
```

I can't figure out why this happens because manually running the command works fine. Is it possible this is related to `sudo` permissions (I was prompted for my sudo password when running the playbook). Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried a `file` task to ensure `/usr/local/lib` exists as a directory first? Seems like a pretty clear error message...

Comment: The directory exists (see the last part of the question where I mentioned that unpacking works fine on the command line).

Comment: run with `-vvv` to see a lot more details about what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an [ansible bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/6723). You will probably be able to work around it if you read the ticket.

Comment: I'd be tempted to convert the tgz into a system package (deb, rpm) etc,  then use package management modules to install it

Comment: v1.9.1 seems fix the problem.